# Launch Console App in Docker Container from VS.NET With Interactive Shell

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio

I'd like to know if it's possible to launch a console app in a docker container from VS.NET (2022) with an interactive shell.  This seems like a simple question and I'm likely just overlooking something basic, but I can't seem to find a solution.  I've tried putting -it in the DockerfileRunArguments in the .csproj file for the console app, but that didn't work.  Is my mindset wrong here?  Should I not be trying to launch docker console app containers from VS.NET interactively?